# I lost my Tumblr 2-factor authentication code

Tags: tumblr

I lost my Tumblr 2-factor authentication code, but I deleted the SMS message on my galaxy Samsung S4. How do I sign back in?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sign in again, and it will send you a new code.